# when I set the tomcat server with the Eclipse,It tells "Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start."

Tags: eclipse, server, tomcat8

in the console,some serious mistake say:

Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]

```
  严重: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
   ... 7 more

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
   ... 9 more

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:925)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
   ... 11 more 
十月 09, 2020 8:19:44 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
信息: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
十月 09, 2020 8:19:44 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
信息: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
十月 09, 2020 8:19:44 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
信息: Stopping service Catalina
十月 09, 2020 8:19:44 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
信息: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
十月 09, 2020 8:19:44 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
严重: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

I try to delete the apache server and reset it,but it don't work,can someone tell a way to handle it?

Comment: Is that the entire log output?

Answer (score 0):

```
十月 10, 2020 12:04:09 下午 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
警告: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ArrangeWeb' did not find a matching property.
十月 10, 2020 12:04:09 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
十月 10, 2020 12:04:09 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: Server built:          Feb 15 2015 18:10:42 UTC
十月 10, 2020 12:04:09 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: Server number:         8.0.20.0
十月 10, 2020 12:04:09 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: OS Name:               Windows 10
十月 10, 2020 12:04:09 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: OS Version:            10.0
十月 10, 2020 12:04:09 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: Architecture:          amd64
十月 10, 2020 12:04:09 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: Java Home:             E:\Program Files (x86)\java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre
十月 10, 2020 12:04:09 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: JVM Version:           1.8.0_161-b12
十月 10, 2020 12:04:09 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
十月 10, 2020 12:04:09 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: CATALINA_BASE:         E:\Program Files\Apache-TomCat-8.0.20\apache-tomcat-8.0.20
十月 10, 2020 12:04:09 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: CATALINA_HOME:         E:\Program Files\Apache-TomCat-8.0.20\apache-tomcat-8.0.20
十月 10, 2020 12:04:09 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=E:\Program Files\Apache-TomCat-8.0.20\apache-tomcat-8.0.20
十月 10, 2020 12:04:09 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=E:\Program Files\Apache-TomCat-8.0.20\apache-tomcat-8.0.20
十月 10, 2020 12:04:09 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=E:\Program Files\eclipise workspace
十月 10, 2020 12:04:09 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=E:\Program Files\Apache-TomCat-8.0.20\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\endorsed
十月 10, 2020 12:04:09 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
信息: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=GBK
十月 10, 2020 12:04:09 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
信息: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: E:\Program Files (x86)\java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;E:/Program Files (x86)/java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/bin/server;E:/Program Files (x86)/java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/bin;E:/Program Files (x86)/java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/lib/amd64;E:\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;"C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32";C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;E:\Program Files (x86)\Node\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;E:\Program Files (x86)\java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;E:\Program Files (x86)\java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\bin;E:\Program Files (x86)\pathon\Scripts\;E:\Program Files (x86)\pathon\;C:\Users\17731\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;E:\Program Files (x86)\fidder\Fiddler;C:\Users\17731\AppData\Roaming\npm;;E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\17731\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;E:\Program Files\Eclipse\eclipse64\eclipse;;.
十月 10, 2020 12:04:10 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
信息: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
十月 10, 2020 12:04:10 下午 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
信息: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
十月 10, 2020 12:04:10 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
信息: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
十月 10, 2020 12:04:10 下午 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
信息: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
十月 10, 2020 12:04:10 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
信息: Initialization processed in 1340 ms
十月 10, 2020 12:04:10 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
信息: Starting service Catalina
十月 10, 2020 12:04:10 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
信息: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
十月 10, 2020 12:04:11 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
严重: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ArrangeWeb]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ArrangeWeb]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: FilterConfig
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredMethods(Introspection.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadMethodsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationFilterAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:64)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5061)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: FilterConfig
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    ... 20 more

十月 10, 2020 12:04:11 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
严重: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:925)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

十月 10, 2020 12:04:11 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
严重: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:925)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

十月 10, 2020 12:04:11 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
信息: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
十月 10, 2020 12:04:11 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
信息: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
十月 10, 2020 12:04:11 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
信息: Stopping service Catalina
十月 10, 2020 12:04:11 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
信息: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
十月 10, 2020 12:04:11 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
严重: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:307)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:482)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:797)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:859)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

十月 10, 2020 12:04:11 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
信息: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
十月 10, 2020 12:04:11 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
严重: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:307)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:482)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:797)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:859)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```